# PowerShell: Reading from Serial breaks and misses characters

Tags: powershell, serial-port, ps

I'd like to read from a Serial connection immediately after sending a command until an "OK" is received:

```
$connection = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort $samsPort,115200,None,8,1
$connection.Open()
$connection.Write("AT+IMEINUM")

While(1)
{
    $result = $connection.ReadLine()
    Write-Host($result)
    
    if($result -like "*OK*")
    {
        Break
    }

}
$connection.Close()
```

The result is:

```
AT+IMEINUM
+IMEINUM: 00000000000000
OK

PS C:\Users\nw\Documents>
```

The expected result in a different terminal is:

```
AT+IMEINUM
+IMEINUM: 00000000000000 /0

+IMEINUM2: 11111111111111 /0

OK
```

For any reason, it strips the second IMEI and the lines plus the "/0" ending.
What I already tried is "ReadExisting", "ReadChar", "ReadTo" (variable) but none of them catches the second IMEI.
I think it breaks at the slash, may this be an encoding error I can fix?

Comment: I see the same behaviour in Realterm (lines end with CRLF) but not in PuTTY ... didn't find out the difference yet

Comment: Looks like the problem is rather on the Write than on the Read site: When I send the command as block (e. g. with paste), I get the same crippled result. Is it possible to transmit char by char without buffer?

Comment: Found a way that works half-good: `Start-Sleep(2)
$connection.Write('A')
$connection.Write('T')
$connection.Write('+')
$connection.Write('I')
$connection.Write('M')
$connection.Write('E')
$connection.Write('I')
$connection.Write('N')
$connection.Write('U')
$connection.Write('M')
Start-Sleep(1)
$connection.Write("`r`n")`
Still buggy (for example the result sometimes begins with "NANANA") but closer to the goal. Will adjust and try more.